# What version of Rubberduck has working source control?

Tags: rubberduck

I'm interested in using Rubberduck primarily for it's Github source control feature. However, from looking at the Github site for the project I can see that in the most recent versions that feature is not so stable. My question is, what version should I use? For now all I really care about is to have the most stable source control feature. Should I go back as far as v1.4.3? Or is there another 2.X version that was more stable before things recently got worse?

Comment: Things didn't recently get worse - the feature is a rather big piece, and it's been needing some love forever. There have been so many improvements in every aspect of everything between 1.4.3 and the latest 2.1.x prerelease build, you don't want 1.4.3. The SC feature and its issues are the same anyway; it's just that the commands were re-wired to a new WPF UI since then. 2.1.x includes an *export project* command that makes it easier to reliably send the code files to the file system. BTW you'll use RD for much more than just SC; the Code Explorer *alone* is a massive navigation tooling boost!

Comment: Mat - thanks for the advice! So if I understand you correctly with using the local git, I'd basically be using RD to sync my code to a local folder, and then using a standalone Git client to take that copy and sync it with Github (do pull requests, etc.) - is that right? The export project command seems like it could work the same way but then it'd only be one way - I could use it to sync the changes I make, but not receive changes that other people make. I'm I tracking correctly here? Thanks again for the quick response! -Michael

Comment: @Mat'sMug ^^^ kinda curious about this too :-)

Comment: Sounds correct indeed; earlier versions had issues mostly involving `UserForm` modules (fixed now, had to do with the .frx not coming along) and dealing with a remote (works but very picky and exception-prone). Note that there's a bug in the VBE that makes it insert blank lines when importing a `UserForm` (manually or programmatically), which messes up the diff - RD removes that empty line when importing a form.

Comment: A pull request was merged yesterday, fixing a dozen source control issues. It's still not perfect, but GitHub authentication and pushing should work now! =)

Answer (score 2):

*EDIT:* As per Vogel's comment

> This answer is outdate since a few months: Source control has been
>   removed completely in the PR #3782 on Feb 26 2018

---

Even so...

I'd definitely recommend trying out Rubberduck; the unit testing, code inspection and other features are awesome... also the guys involved are generous with sharing their time and knowledge - but IMHO would shy away from using an old version to gain access to the Git features (it has been disabled for a reason).

You can enable it as an 'Experimental Feature' under the menu system > Rubberduck > Settings > General Settings (scroll down)

[image: Rubberduck settings for using Git]

If you really need something ASAP perhaps look at VBAdiff (http://vbadiff.com/) or this project https://github.com/spences10/VBA-IDE-Code-Export

Answer (score 0):

The bulk of the efforts of the past couple of months went to perfecting the parser and resolver, which impacts overall performance and all inspections and refactoring features; eliminating inspection false positives and making sure no quickfix or refactoring wrecked our users' code has been the top priority, leaving the borked source control panel under-loved - so much that we recently outright disabled it by default, until we *git* it under control.

Teams mean to grow, and a new contributor joined the project and started working on the source control panel issues.

A pull request was merged recently,
and since every merged PR gets a prerelease CI build published, [v2.1.0.2257](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/releases/tag/Rubberduck-v2.1.0.2257) is now available for download.

This fixes an IoC registration bug involving an abstract factory interface that the SC panel uses, and it just so happens to apparently fix the exceptions with GitHub authentication, so pushing should now work fine.

More fixes on the way, v2.1 "green release" will likely have a pretty much stable source control feature =)